# Rename [borderlands-2-ttaodk] → [borderlands-2-tiny-tinas-assault]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

*[Borderlands 2: Tiny Tina's Assault on Dragon Keep](http://www.ign.com/articles/2013/06/25/borderlands-2-tiny-tinas-assault-on-dragon-keep-review)* currently has the severely abbreviated tag [borderlands-2-ttaodk](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/borderlands-2-ttaodk). While [borderlands-2-tiny-tinas-assault-on-dragon-keep](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/borderlands-2-tiny-tinas-assault-on-dragon-keep) is too long (47 characters), it would probably benefit us to rename to [borderlands-2-tiny-tinas-assault](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/borderlands-2-tiny-tinas-assault) (33 characters).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Done:**

- [borderlands-2-ttaodk](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/borderlands-2-ttaodk) → [borderlands-2-tiny-tinas-assault](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/borderlands-2-tiny-tinas-assault)

Comment: I deleted the tiny-tinas-assault-on-dragon-keep synonym, so that it could be used for the 2021 standalone game, as described  in this meta https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16722/should-there-be-a-separate-tag-for-questions-on-the-tiny-tina-attack-on-dragon-k