# Should there be a separate tag for questions on the Tiny Tina Assault on Dragon Keep standalone?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are a few tag synonyms for DLC4 of Borderlands 2, Tiny Tina’s Assault on Dragon Keep. However, in 2021 Gearbox released a “standalone” version of the DLC, which includes changes to the leveling system, some map tweaks, and a couple other differences.

While they are very similar, there are key differences, and as such, I think it would be worth it to include a separate tag. However, I’m not sure how to disambiguate it from the Borderlands 2 DLC4 tag(s) such as the ones listed [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12905/rename-borderlands-2-ttaodk-%E2%86%92-borderlands-2-tiny-tinas-assault).

As far as I can tell there are no questions on this yet, but I recently picked up the game for free on a Steam sale and have had a few questions I’ve been trying to answer and it didn’t seem right to use the standard DLC-related tag (since I very much know the answer in the Borderlands 2 DLC, but *not* whether it’s something that’s changed in the standalone)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe [this](https://store.steampowered.com/app/1712840/Tiny_Tinas_Assault_on_Dragon_Keep_A_Wonderlands_Oneshot_Adventure/) is the game you are talking about, which is titled *Tiny Tina's Assault on Dragon Keep: A Wonderlands One-shot Adventure*.  That is already way too long for the tag character limit.

The DLC tag has *Borderlands-2* in it, and this game doesn't. Thus, I'd say an appropriate tag is [tiny-tinas-assault-on-dragon-keep](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tiny-tinas-assault-on-dragon-keep). As such, I've deleted this synonym so that a new standalone tag can be made.

Seeing that you have enough reputation to create tags (300+), you can make this tag at the time you ask your question(s). Also, it would be appreciated if you could maybe add a tag wiki and excerpt that clearly explains what game the tag is for!

Comment: Thanks! I’ll do so; I really didn’t want to try to figure out how to tag it without making things *more* confusing rather than less

Comment: It’s taken long enough but I did get around to wiring up the tag definition. I definitely cribbed some notes off of the original [tag:borderlands-2-tiny-tinas-assault] tag wiki for how to write a decent wiki, though I did write up the usage section separately. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

This is in connection with [Timmy Jim's answer](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16723/4797). I agree with the tag name suggestion and have approved your tag wiki edit. I made some additional changes to address possible questions from askers about common gameplay elements between the original DLC and the standalone game.

The [tiny-tinas-assault-on-dragon-keep](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tiny-tinas-assault-on-dragon-keep) tag wiki excerpt (usage guidance) now is:

> "Tiny Tina's Assault on Dragon Keep: A Wonderlands One-Shot Adventure" is the standalone re-release of the "Tiny Tina's Assault on Dragon Keep" DLC from Borderlands 2. It was developed by Gearbox Software and Stray Kite Studios, and released in 2021. This tag should NOT be used for questions about the Borderlands 2 DLC. This tag is distinct from the original DLC tag and should only be used together when asking about common gameplay elements.

and the "tag notes" section of the tag wiki is:

> Use this tag if your question is specific to *Tiny Tina's Assault on Dragon Keep: A Wonderlands One-Shot Adventure*. Otherwise, use one of the related tags below. If you are asking about the *Borderlands 2* DLC, use [borderlands-2-tiny-tinas-assault](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/borderlands-2-tiny-tinas-assault) and [borderlands-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/borderlands-2). This tag is distinct from the original DLC-related tag and should only be used together when asking about common gameplay elements.

Feel free to suggest improvements to the tag wiki.